# Dotted line not enveloping the intended part (Recent employment history) - Where is the fault?

Tags: html, css

I can't figure out why the dotted line border for the "employmentFrame" div is not enveloping the inner contents like is the case with "frame" div higher up in the code. As far as I can see I have coded it the same way, with the difference that there is an extra nesting in the one which is working. Or maybe I'm wrong. In any case, I'm just not seeing it. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with this code?

EDIT:
So the dotted line underneath "Personal details" is exactly as I want it to be. The problem is with the dotted line underneath "Recent employment history". Currently that shows as a horizontal line, but it is supposed to go around the information underneath it.

```css
body {
  font-family: Cambria, Georgia, serif;
  background-color: black;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  color: rgb(54, 95, 145);
}

h2 {
  font-size: 1.5vw;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainBox {
  width: 90vw;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
}

.margin {
  height: 5vw;
}

.contentBox {
  width: 80vw;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: auto;
}

.horizontalLine {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5vw;
  background-color: rgb(184, 204, 228);
  clear: both;
}

.horizontalEmpty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1.5vw;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  width: 49%;
}

.sectionTitle {
  height: 1.9vw;
  background-color: rgb(184, 204, 228);
  padding-left: 1vw;
}

.sectionEmpty {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.75vw;
  clear: both;
}

.frame {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: rgb(184, 204, 228);
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 99.7%;
  clear: both;
}

.frameContent {
  width: 95%;
  margin: auto;
}

.employmentFrame {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-color: rgb(184, 204, 228);
  border-width: 1px;
  padding-left: 1vw;
  clear: both;
}

.employmentFrameContent {
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.row {
  height: 2vw;
}

.property {
  width: 30%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: rgb(54, 95, 145);
  float: left;
}

.value {
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 1.3vw;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainBox">
  <div class="margin"></div>
  <div class="contentBox">
    <div id="title" style="text-align: center; height: 3.5vw">
      <h1>Curriculum Vitae</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontalLine"></div>
    <div class="horizontalEmpty"></div>
    <div class="column" style="float: left">
      <div class="sectionTitle">
        <h2>Personal details</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="frameContent">
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Full name</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Nationality</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Date of birth</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Street name</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">City</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Post code</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Email</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Mobile</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="float: right">
      <div class="sectionTitle">
        <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="frame">
        <div class="frameContent">
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="horizontalEmpty"></div>
    <div class="sectionTitle">
      <h2>Recent employment history</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
    <div class="employmentFrame">
      <div class="employmentFrameContent">
        <div class="column" style="float:left">
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Period</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Title</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Company</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Address</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Telephone</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Manager</div>
            <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="column" style="float:right">
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="property">Details</div>
          </div>
          <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="margin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: So do you want the dotted line to be around the fields like 'name' and 'nationality' ?Also, I would suggest you edit your question title to make it more relevant to the question before they start downvoting it, currently your question title is pretty vague. Just trying to help :)

Comment: Thanks. I edited the title. The first dotted line around the information underneath "Personal details" is just as I want it to be. The problem is the other dotted line underneath "Recent employment history". Currently it just shows as a horizontal line, but it's supposed to go around the information underneath it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is due to your inline float: left on the column, the outer box needs to be cleared of the floats inside in order to have layout. Read about the clearfix hack https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_float.asp

There are other solutions to this problem too, use flexbox instead of floats or add a DOM element after the floats with a clear: both on it.

## UPDATE

The simplest solution is below:

```
<div class="employmentFrameContent">
    <div class="column" style="float:left">
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Period</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Title</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Company</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Address</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet<br />Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Telephone</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Manager</div>
        <div class="value">Dolor sit amet</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column" style="float:right">
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="property">Details</div>
      </div>
      <div class="sectionEmpty"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I already have a clear command in the employmentFrame class. Just added "clear: both" to the employmentFrameContent class as well. It didn't change anything. Which class or div is supposed to be cleared here in order for that to have the appropriate effect? I've been reading up on the clear command since last night (among other things of course) but the W3 schools examples don't really show me how it works in a way that seems to stick for me.

Comment: I have updated with the simplest solution, this however is not the best as you should try and remove all inline style tags, they should all be attached to classes that can then be easily re-used. As for the clearfix this is a common CSS pattern you can read up on this here https://css-tricks.com/clearfix-a-lesson-in-web-development-evolution/

Comment: Thanks for the update @GInger CSS Wizard! That sure did fix it for me. I am wondering though why putting the "clear: both" command in the definition of the "employmentFrame" and "employmentFrameContent" classes didn't have the same effect. Could you possibly explain that for me as well?

Comment: I have found now that I had not yet put the "sectionEmpty" div at the bottom before closing the "employmentFrameContent" tag. This class already has the "clear: both" command in it, so this works the same way as the in-line solution you provided and so now the command isn't in-line anymore either, as you suggested. Thanks for all your help with this @Ginger_CSS_Wizard!

Comment: The clear property only works directly after the elements that are floating it does not work when applied to to the parent elements. The clear CSS property sets whether an element must be moved below (cleared) floating elements that precede it. The clear property applies to floating and non-floating elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear